# How to add typescript type to ES6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Nowadays, I need to update javascript code to typescript.

But I found a question.

Before, I use a lot of arrow functions in before project. Now, I need to add type definition for many of them like after:

```
(a: number): string => { return `${a}` }
```

By using many npm packages, the package provide function type like after:

```
export declare type AAACallback = (a: number) => string
```

I wanna use the function type to my es6 arrow function.

Maybe you say like this:

```
let a: AAACallback = a => { return `${a}` }

// then use a
```

But I don't need to define a at all.

So, do you have any way to use function definition with es6 arrow function without define other variate?

Comment: Interesting you use the word “update” when referring to converting to typescript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox maybe I mean rewrite. you have any idea about my question?

Comment: @TomIsion not really clear to me what you are asking? You have a callback type `AAACallback` you assign an arrow function to it. What is the question ? You want to declare the type of `a` without the extra type ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir `AAACallback` is typescript function type. I wanna use it to define my arrow function.

Comment: @TomIsion still not clear to me what you want to do and can't `let a: AAACallback = a => { return ``${a}`` }` defines an arrow function of type `AAACallback` What do you want to write and can't ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir during writing javascript, arrow function always use without define name, like handle event callback: `element.addEventListener('click', event => (), false)`, I wanna use the `AAACallback` typescript type to define the no name arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't have a built-in syntax to annotate that an arrow function (or any other expression) has a given overall type without declaring a separate variable.  (If you use a type assertion, you may be unintentionally downcasting the expression since type assertions allow both upcasts and downcasts.)  One thing you can do is use an identity function:

```
function id<T>(arg: T) { return arg; }

element.addEventListener('click', id<AAACallback>(event => {}), false)
```